# Are there any gotchas with open(my $f, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $n)

Tags: perl

I am having a problem that I am unable to reproduce in a manner suitable for Stackoverflow although it's reproducable in my production environment.

The problem occors in a Perl script that, among others, iterates over a file that looks like so:

```
abc-4-9|free text, possibly containing non-ascii characters|
cde-3-8|hällo wörld|
# comment

xyz-9-1|and so on|
qrs-2-8|and so forth|
```

I can verify the correctness of the file with this Perl script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (my $f, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'c:\path\to\file') or die "$!";

while (my $s = <$f>) {
  chomp($s);
  next unless $s;
  next if $s =~ m/^#/;
  $s =~ m!(\w+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\|([^|]*)\|! or die "\n>$s<\n didn't match on line $.";
}

print "Ok\n";
close $f;
```

When I run this script, it won't die on line 10 and consequently print `Ok`.

Now, I use essentially the same construct in a huge Perl script (hence irreproducable for Stackoverflow) and it will die on line 2199 of the input file.

If I change the first line (which is completely unrelated to line 2199) from something like

```
 www-1-1|A line with some words|
```

to

```
 www-1-1|x|
```

the script will process line 2199 (but fail later).

Interestingly, this behaviour was introduced when I changed

```
open (my $f, '<', 'c:\path\to\file') or die "$!";
```

to

```
open (my $f, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'c:\path\to\file') or die "$!";
```

Without the `:encoding(UTF-8)` directive, the script does not fail. Of course, I need the encoding directive since the file contains non-ascii characters.

BTW, the same script runs without problems on Linux.

On Windows, where it fails, I use Strawberry Perl 5.24

Comment: The file does not have a BOM. As it contains confidential data, I cannot unfortunately just copy and paste the first few lines.

Comment: Add `use Devel::Peek;` and replace `die ...` with `Dump($s), die ...`. Please provide the output.

Comment: Alternatively, replace `die ..."` with `do { use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; die Dumper($s)." ".( utf8::is_utf8($s)?1:0 )." at line $. didn't match" };`

Comment: @SinanÜnür your suggestion actually *did* fix the problem... Please turn it into an answer so I can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a full and correct explanation of why this is necessary, but you can try opening the file with

```
'<:unix:encoding(UTF-8)'
```

This may be related to my question "[Why is CRLF set for the unix layer on Windows?](https://www.nu42.com/2014/05/utf-8-output-from-perl-in-cmdexe-layers.html)" which I noticed when I was trying to figure out stuff which I ended up never figuring out.